# Multiple clicks on uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Is there some way to change uitableview cell size according to the click on cell? For example: cell with width 100.0f, on first click cell changes width to 150.0f and for second click cell changes width back to 100.0f. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to index an NSMutableDictionary with NSIndexPath objects. This will let you cache the sizes you want for your clicked TVCells. Then just pull them out at runtime:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   NSNumber *newHeight;
   NSNumber *height = [[self heightCache] objectForKey:indexPath];

   if (height == nil) newHeight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0];
   else newHeight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[height doubleValue] + 50];
   [[self heightCache] setObject:newHeight forKey:indexPath];
   [tableView reloadData]; // also consider reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:
}
```

Meanwhile in your delegate:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSNumber height = [heightCache objectForKey:indexPath];
   return height == nil ? defaultHeight : [height floatValue];
}
```

**UPDATE:** Oh oops, I thought you meant the TVCells to just get bigger and bigger. Yes, just change the floats in my example to bools, and then in height for row return the height based on the bool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a bool value, change this bool value on each subsequent click.

Now based upon this bool define your `cellForRowAtIndexPathmethod` and on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method just update the bool and reload the `table`.